# PermissionError on writable file in Jenkins

Tags: python, file, jenkins

I'm trying to open a file in python that was opening fine before with this syntax, but now that I've rearranged directories I am getting a `PermissionError` and I cannot pinpoint why. I have directory `ahs_reports` containing files `create_ahs_report.py` and `message_body.html`. `ahs_report` is contained in a directory called `reports`. `message_body.html` has permissions `-rwxrwxrwx` so it should be writable. `ahs_report/` also has the same permissions. However, when I run `create_ahs_report.py` from directory `reports`, and get to this line

```
with open('message_body.html', 'w+') as f:
```

I get `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'message_body.html'`. I feel like there's something obvious I am missing. What is it? I am running the script thru a Jenkins job as user jenkins and I've never had an issue like this.

Comment: check _current_ directory. It may have changed. `print(os.getcwd())` before opening the file, you may get a surprise.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Doi! That showed I was not in the right place. Thank you.

Comment: that's a classic. I'm glad you sorted this out.